# How to manage visibility settings in Composite Envelope

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to work with visibility settings in a workflow using the docusign api. The workflow consists of two inline templates and I want to restrict it so a signer cannot see 1 document in the second inline template. Here is the json being sent to DocuSign:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "High School Faculty"
              },
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "High School Administration"
              },
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "4",
                "roleName": "Department Dean"
              },
              {
                "documentVisibility": [
                  {
                    "documentId": "2",
                    "recipientId": "5",
                    "visible": "false"
                  }
                ],
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "5",
                "roleName": "Department Faculty"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "900cc73b-f35c-45b1-92d1-e8453094aa60"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentBase64": <data>, 
              "documentId": "1",
              "fileExtension": "docx",
              "name": "Packet"
            },
            {
              "documentBase64": <data>,
              "documentId": "2",
              "fileExtension": "docx",
              "name": "Packet"
            }
          ],
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "High School Faculty"
              },
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "High School Administration"
              },
              {
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "4",
                "roleName": "Department Dean"
              },
              {
                "documentVisibility": [
                  {
                    "documentId": "2",
                    "recipientId": "5",
                    "visible": "false"
                  }
                ],
                "email": ,
                "name": ,
                "recipientId": "5",
                "roleName": "Department Faculty"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "College Now Master Form",
  "enforceSignerVisibility": "true"
}
```

When I go through testing the workflow the Department Faculty is still able to view the 2nd Document in the second inline template. I am testing so I am using the same signin for each role, could this be the issue? Can anyone point to what I am doing wrong? We do have visibility turned on for our instance. Thanks!

Comment: So it looks like I should have been using: "excludedDocuments": [
                  "2"] as part of the signer and not "documentVisibility". It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [EnvelopeRecipients](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/) docs, you'll want to use the ExcludedDocuments parameter to define it as a part of the Recipient object:

```
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "name": "Example Signer",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder":1,
        "excludedDocuments":[2],
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "xPosition": "150",
              "yPosition": "150",
              "pageNumber":1
            }
          ]
        }
    }]
}
```

You'll also want to confirm how your account has Document Visibility configured, as it can be set to exclude the sender alone, or members of the sender's account. If it's set to "unless member of signer's account", testing may be thrown off.